# Automatically setting an enum member's value to its name

Tags: python, enums, metaprogramming, metaclass

I've been messing around with python's enum library and have come across a conundrum. In the docs, they show an example of an [auto-numbering enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#autonumber), wherein something is defined:

```
class Color(AutoNumber):
    red = ()
    green = ()
    ...
```

I want to make a similar class, but the value would automatically be set from the name of the member AND keep the functionality that you get from doing the `str` and `enum` [mixin stuff](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum)

So something like:

```
class Animal(MagicStrEnum):
    horse = ()
    dog = ()

Animal.dog == 'dog' # True
```

I've looked at the source code of the enum module and tried a lot of variations messing around with `__new__` and the `EnumMeta` class

Comment: do you mean `Animal.dog.value == 'dog'`?

Comment: related:  http://www.acooke.org/cute/Pythonssad0.html

Comment: I think it could be done by modifying EnumMeta._create_() in enum.py (https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/enum.py#l295, however that cannot be immediately overriden due to ValueError on sundered names coming from _is_sunder() to protect the code. However, if names = ['red','green','blue'] and Color = Enum('Color', names=zip(names,names)), then Color.red.value == 'red', Color.green.value == 'green' and Color.blue.value == 'blue'.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 44):

*Update: 2017-03-01*

> In Python 3.6 (and [`Aenum 2.0`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup>) [`Flag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#flag) and [`IntFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intflag) classes have been added; part of that was a new [`auto()` helper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values) that makes this trivially easy:

```
>>> class AutoName(Enum):
...     def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
...         return name
...
>>> class Ordinal(AutoName):
...     NORTH = auto()
...     SOUTH = auto()
...     EAST = auto()
...     WEST = auto()
...
>>> list(Ordinal)
[<Ordinal.NORTH: 'NORTH'>, <Ordinal.SOUTH: 'SOUTH'>, <Ordinal.EAST: 'EAST'>, <Ordinal.WEST: 'WEST'>]
```

---

*Original answer*

The difficulty with an `AutoStr` class is that the name of the enum member is not passed into the code that creates it, so it is unavailable for use.  Another wrinkle is that `str` is immutable, so we can't change those types of enums after they have been created (by using a [class decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators), for example).

The easiest thing to do is use the [Functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api):

```
Animal = Enum('Animal', [(a, a) for a in ('horse', 'dog')], type=str)
```

which gives us:

```
>>> list(Animal)
[<Animal.horse: 'horse'>, <Animal.dog: 'dog'>]

>>> Animal.dog == 'dog'
True
```

---

The next easiest thing to do, assuming you want to make a base class for your future enumeration use, would be something like my `DocEnem`:

```
class DocEnum(Enum):
    """
    compares equal to all cased versions of its name
    accepts a doctring for each member
    """
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        """Ignores arguments (will be handled in __init__)"""
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = None
        return obj

    def __init__(self, doc=None):
        # first, fix _value_
        self._value_ = self._name_.lower()
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, basestring):
            return self._value_ == other.lower()
        elif not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return NotImplemented
        return self is other

    def __hash__(self):
        # keep DocEnum hashable
        return hash(self._value_)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other
```

and in use:

```
class SpecKind(DocEnum):
    REQUIRED = "required value"
    OPTION = "single value per name"
    MULTI = "multiple values per name (list form)"
    FLAG = "boolean value per name"
    KEYWORD = 'unknown options'
```

Note that unlike the first option, `DocEnum` members are *not* `str`s.

---

If you want to do it the hard way:  subclass `EnumMeta` and fiddle with the new `Enum`'s class dictionary *before* the members are created:

```
from enum import EnumMeta, Enum, _EnumDict

class StrEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, oldclassdict):
        """
        Scan through `oldclassdict` and convert any value that is a plain tuple
        into a `str` of the name instead
        """
        newclassdict = _EnumDict()
        for k, v in oldclassdict.items():
            if v == ():
                v = k
            newclassdict[k] = v
        return super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, newclassdict)

class AutoStrEnum(str, Enum, metaclass=StrEnumMeta):
    "base class for name=value str enums"

class Animal(AutoStrEnum):
    horse = ()
    dog = ()
    whale = ()

print(Animal.horse)
print(Animal.horse == 'horse')
print(Animal.horse.name, Animal.horse.value)
```

Which gives us:

```
Animal.horse
True
horse horse
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: @VillasV: Thanks for finding that error!  I'm sorry the reviewers didn't see it was a correct edit.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Just one problem: Although subclassed from `Enum`, `DocEnum` seems to not have a `__hash__` method. I have to manually copy `Enum.__hash__` to make `DocEnum` hashable. Why is that?

Comment: @ComeOnGetMe: In Python 3 if an `__eq__` is defined then `__hash__` is set to `None` unless `__hash__` is defined (or set to something else) in the class.  Answer updated.

Comment: This no longer works in 3.9 because the private `_EnumDict` has changed.

Comment: @gps: I just tested the top most solution of my answer, and the original solution in my answer, from Pythons 3.6 - 3.11, and both worked in every version.  Exactly what did you try?

Comment: The latter one, the subclass, doesn't work as of 3.9.

Comment: @gps (forgot to mention you in my reply): As I said yesterday, I have copy/pasted that code into a file, ran it with Python 3.9 (in fact, all Pythons between 3.6 and 3.11, inclusive), and I get the correct results with 3.9 and all the others. (And I just rebuilt 3.9.8 to make sure.) Can you email me the exact details of what you are doing? If you've found a bug I'd like to fix it. Oh, and the only change to `_EnumDict` in 3.9 is a warning if the member name is name mangled.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the `name` attribute which is automatically provided by the [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) class

```
>>> class Animal(Enum):
...     ant = 1
...     bee = 2
...     cat = 3
...     dog = 4
...

>>> Animal.ant.name == "ant"
True
```

Though if you really want to shoot yourself in the foot. And I'm sure this will introduce a whole world of gotchas (I've eliminated the most obvious one).

```
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta, _EnumDict

class AutoStrEnumDict(_EnumDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, key)

class AutoStrEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, cls, bases):
        return AutoStrEnumDict()
    def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
        super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        # override Enum.__str__
        # can't put these on the class directly otherwise EnumMeta overwrites them
        # should also consider resetting __repr__, __format__ and __reduce_ex__
        if self.__str__ is not str.__str__:
            self.__str__ = str.__str__

class AutoStrNameEnum(str, Enum, metaclass=AutoStrEnumMeta):
    pass

class Animal(AutoStrNameEnum):
    horse = ()
    dog = ()

print(Animal.horse)
assert Animal.horse == "horse"
assert str(Animal.horse) == "horse" 
# and not equal to "Animal.horse" (the gotcha mentioned earlier)
```

Comment: Your modification to `_EnumDict` makes it impossible to add methods as they would also be converted to `str`s.

Comment: Easy to get around. Either check to see if the value is a function. Or to make it more robust, create a sentinel value and only do the conversion when the value is the sentinel.