# Python Enum combination

Tags: python, enums, metaprogramming, python-3.5, metaclass

I would like to create a new Enum (IntEnum) class based on two existing ones. There is a working solution for this, like so:

```
from enum import unique, IntEnum
from itertools import chain
from collections import OrderedDict

@unique
class FirstEnumClass(IntEnum):
    a = 1
    b = 2

@unique
class SecondEnumClass(IntEnum):
    c = 3
    d = 4

# here a combined class is created:
CombinedEnumClass = unique(IntEnum('CombinedEnumClass', OrderedDict([(i.name, i.value) for i in chain(FirstEnumClass, SecondEnumClass)])))
```

My question: is there a fancy way to achieve this, so that there is a proper class definition? Like overriding some of the metaclass methods, or so? I would like something like this, so that docstring can also be given:

```
@unique
class CombinedEnumClass(IntEnum):
    """ docstring """
    # magic needed here
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `OrderedDict`, you can give just the list comprehension.

Comment: I know, it works that way, the thing is that I'm using PyCharm, and it gives a warning if just a list is given: "Expected type 'Integral', got 'List[Tuple[Any, Any]]' instead", and OrderedDict solved that. But true, it works without that. Anyways, I still cannot manage to do this like a class definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend Python Enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679930/how-to-extend-python-enum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library [prevents explicitly](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing) to do that:

> Subclassing an enumeration is allowed only if the enumeration does not
> define any members.
>
> Allowing subclassing of enums that define members would lead to a
> violation of some important invariants of types and instances. On the
> other hand, it makes sense to allow sharing some common behavior
> between a group of enumerations.

Therefore, I found a [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41807919/4530440) using almost the same workaround as you do. I think this is the only way.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like this is the only way. meanwhile I tried something like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214614/automatically-setting-an-enum-members-value-to-its-name), to subclass the EnumMeta metaclass itself and play with its `__new__` method, but eventually all try runs into the same problem: `TypeError: Cannot extend enumerations`.

Answer (score 7):

**Python 2**

Using a trick with `vars()` this can be accomplished:

```
class CombinedEnum(IntEnum):
    """ doc string """
    cls = vars()
    for member in chain(list(FirstEnumClass), list(SecondEnumClass)):
        cls[member.name] = member.value
    del member, cls

print(list(CombinedEnum))
```

This works because:

- `vars()` returns the current namespace
- modifying that namespace modifies the class

We delete `member` and `cls` because we don't want them to become members.

---

**Python 3**

The above doesn't (yet) work with the new `Enum` in Python3 3.4 and 3.5 (not sure about 3.6).  The work-a-round is to use [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) instead, which allows us to tell `Enum` to ignore certain names:

```
from aenum import IntEnum

class CombinedEnum(IntEnum):
    """ doc string """
    _ignore_ = 'member cls'
    cls = vars()
    for member in chain(list(FirstEnumClass), list(SecondEnumClass)):
        cls[member.name] = member.value
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: It looks good, but it does not work for me:
`File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py", line 66, in __setitem__
 raise TypeError('Attempted to reuse key: %r' % key)
 TypeError: Attempted to reuse key: 'member'`

I tried to skip the `cls[member.name] = member.value` line and write a `pass` instead, but still the same is raised.
I use Python 3.5.2 with Anaconda3.

Comment: I tried it in Python 2.7, and it works there. Do you know a way for Python 3.x?

Comment: @waszil:  Thanks for finding that.  I added a Python 3 work around.

Comment: @EthanFurman, so why did you [restrict subclassing of enumerations?]( https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#restricted-subclassing-of-enumerations) in the first place. And what does `_ignore_` var is doing? Thanks for your libraries.

Comment: @OwlMax:  subclassing added complications with equality and identity, and we didn't feel it was a net win to allow it; The `_ignore_` variable is telling the `Enum` metaclass to discard those names from the final enum class.

Comment: @EthanFurman I have posted a question on enum about "Combine two or more enumeration classes in order to have more levels access". If you have some tips,  I am infinitely grateful to you. Thanks in advance 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71527981/combine-two-or-more-enumeration-classes-in-order-to-have-more-levels-access