# Combine two or more enumeration classes in order to have more levels access

Tags: python, enums

I wish to know if this is the best way to combine two or more Python Enum classes into a final class that collects each Enum class and to have a more levels.

Consider the example of @EthanFurman in the page [Python Enum combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073413/python-enum-combination)

```
from enum import Enum, unique
from itertools import chain

@unique
class Letters(Enum):
    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'
    C = 'c'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

@unique
class Numbers(Enum):
    ONE = 'one'
    TWO = 'two'
    THREE = 'three'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
```

Etahn Furman suggests the following class of combination:

```
class CombinedEnum(Enum):
    """ doc string """
    _ignore_ = 'member cls'
    cls = vars()
    for member in chain(list(Letters), list(Numbers)):
        cls[member.name] = member.value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(str(CombinedEnum.A))
    print(str(CombinedEnum.B))
    print(str(CombinedEnum.C))
    print(str(CombinedEnum.ONE))
    print(str(CombinedEnum.TWO))
    print(str(CombinedEnum.THREE))
```

However, the multi-level class I would like to create should access the values in the following way:

```
CombinedEnum.Letters.A
CombinedEnum.Letters.B
CombinedEnum.Letters.C

CombinedEnum.Numbers.ONE
CombinedEnum.Numbers.TWO
CombinedEnum.Numbers.THREE
```

Typically, the basic solution I use is to use a composition class where the variables are the various Enum classes.

```
class World:
    """ doc string """
    LETTERS = Letters
    NUMBERS = Numbers
```

Comment: what is wrong with your composition?

Comment: I'm not sure it is the best and most elegant way to combine two or more classes of type Enum

Comment: i can't really comment in general - but i would use that. it is simple and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to use `World` and `A`, `B`, `C`, `ONE`, `TWO`, and `THREE`:

- will you be checking to see if `A` is an instance of `World`?
- do `A` and `ONE` need to be part of the same enum?

If the answer to both of those is "no", then your `World` class is probably fine.

Comment: Hey Ethan thanks for your replay and thanks for your Enum work (I love it!). The choice of composition is not perfect because using my IDE (Pycharm) the "value" method (and "name") is not (e.g. World.NUMBERS.value) hidden causing an exception to be raised if it is inadvertently chosen by the developer. i.e., "raise AttributeError(name) from None AttributeError: value".

Comment: @GianniSpear: In your example above, `World` is not an enum, so `World.NUMBERS.value` *is* an error.

Comment: hey Ethan, World is a composition class. I did not figure out a way to make a composition of enum class